# Trouble understanding React stale state in Counter example

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm sure my issues is around useCallback and the setter method I have here `setSpeakers` returned from `useState` but I'm not understanding exactly why my example, as listed here and in codesandbox is not incrementing the state correctly.  The old state keeps being returned, not the new incremented state.  When I pass a function into `setSpeakers` instead of just a new state, my example works (you can see the commented out code marked THIS CODE WORKS below the non-working code.

I know others have written articles on this and I've read those articles but still don't get it.

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-lichterman-7rejs?file=/pages/index.js

```
import React, { useState, memo, useCallback } from "react";

//const Speaker = React.memo(({ imageSrc, counter, setCounter }) => {
const Speaker = ({ speaker, speakerClick }) => {
  console.log(speaker.id);
  return (
    <div>
      <span
        onClick={() => {
          speakerClick(speaker.id);
        }}
        src={`speakerimages/Speaker-${speaker.id}.jpg`}
        width={100}
      >
        {speaker.id} {speaker.name}
      </span>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <span className="fa fa-star ">&nbsp;&nbsp;{speaker.clickCount}</span>
      &nbsp;
    </div>
  );
};

function SpeakerList({ speakers, setSpeakers }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {speakers.map((speaker) => {
        return (
          <Speaker
            speaker={speaker}
            speakerClick={useCallback((id) => {


              // THIS CODE FAILS BECAUSE OF STALE STATE BUT I DON'T GET WHY
              const speakersNew = speakers.map((speaker) => {
                return speaker.id === id
                  ? { ...speaker, clickCount: speaker.clickCount + 1 }
                  : speaker;
              });
              setSpeakers(speakersNew);

              // THIS CODE WORKS
              // setSpeakers(function(speakers) {
              //   const speakersNew = speakers.map((speaker) => {
              //     return speaker.id === id
              //         ? { ...speaker, clickCount: speaker.clickCount + 1 }
              //         : speaker;
              //   });
              //   return speakersNew;
              // });



            }, [])}
            key={speaker.id}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

//
const App = () => {
  const speakersArray = [
    { id: 1124, name: "aaa", clickCount: 0 },
    { id: 1530, name: "bbb", clickCount: 0 },
    { id: 10803, name: "ccc", clickCount: 0 }
  ];

  const [speakers, setSpeakers] = useState(speakersArray);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Speaker List</h1>
      <SpeakerList speakers={speakers} setSpeakers={setSpeakers}></SpeakerList>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because set state works asynchronously. In the first code that isn't running you set the state and try to immediately have it show up which wont work since there is delay while the state is being set. The second one works because you're passing a callback to set state which basically means set the state and do this while you're at it. while the first one means set the state and then do this afterwards. That's not what you want. Its a loose analogy but look into how and why set state is aync you'll have a better idea. Cheers.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around whether it's ever OK to call setState without a function.  I know calling setState multiple times in a row is a fail, but not sure when it's OK to pass an object and not a function

Comment: If you're using it inside a function then you can pass an object you would only need a callback when you want instant results like console.log immediately after setting a state wont work with an object but will work if you pass a callback. Similarly when you want to set state and do something immediately afterwards with it should be dealt with in the callback.

Comment: and no both are ok ways there is nothing wrong with passing an object or a function it just depends on you're requirement usually an object is used because the UI would update anyways after setting the state. The function is used when you want to do some data manipulation before setting the state like deleting an index for example.

Comment: I get why console.log does not work, but still don't get why my example code with setSpeakers has the state being stale.  It feels like setSpeakers, since it happens in SpeakerList, that speaker should get updated state as it's part of the UI rendered.

Comment: Also, when I remove the useCallback, the problem does not exist anymore.  That confused me how useCallback causes the state to be stale.